# How to wait for my variable returned from a function to be Defined before rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a function in one react component to fetch me some data.

The functions looks like this

```
export function FetchWithKeyw(keyw){
  
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("************:8000/"+keyw)
    .then(res => {
        setData(res.data);
    },[])
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
        
    },[])
  },[])
  
  return data
```

And the component looks like this

```
function Aboutus(props) {

    const latestdatas = FetchWithKeyw("car")
    console.log(latestdatas[0])
    return(
.....
       <PreviewDataset image="/420X358-7.jpg" title={latestdatas[0].Title} desc=     {latestdatas[0].Description} category={latestdatas[0].Indicator_Class}
.....
```

The console log **console.log(latestdatas[0])** shows correctly exept the first time which shows undefined and i believe it is rendered quickly before the call finishes and when it reaches the **PreviewDataset** the *undefined* doesn't have a value of *.Title* and it brakes.

I have tried to implement a *Loading Transition* to wait

```
const latestdatas = FetchWithKeyw("car")
console.log(latestdatas[0])
if (latestdatas[0] === undefined) {
   return <LoadingTransition></LoadingTransition>;
}
return(
......
```

but it still breaks.

How can i make it so it waits for the component to wait for the API call to finish and then render?

Thank you all in advance!!

**EDIT**
**I had not writen correctly the Loading trantition component
but with changes it works correctly.**

I am still interested if this is the better way of dealing with this so if you care to comment with a more proper idea i would be happy!

Comment: is there a reason you are using a custom hook? - also: names of custom hooks should start with "use" - 1stly so that your linter may find bugs 2ndly so that others understand that they are looking at a custom hook

Comment: The only hook i am using is the useEffect in the function but  believe this follows your instructions.

Comment: the fact that you didn't mean or intend to create a custom hook creates a whole new problem. React hooks should only be used in Components (or custom hooks), you should never call hooks from normal JS functions. - Your function "FetchWithKeyw" is not a component and was not intended to be a custom hook - so there should be no hooks (useEffect and useState) used inside of it.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII  I searched what you meant and you are right i will try to change it to follow the hook rules . Thank you for your comments , i appreciate the help.